# "No supported authentication methods available" while connecting to SFTP using WinSCP in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winscp, winscp-net

I'm trying to connect to a SFTP server using WinSCP in C#. This is my code:

```
SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
{
    Protocol = Protocol.Sftp,
    HostName = "ip",
    PortNumber = portNR,
    UserName = "username",
    Password = "",
    SshHostKeyFingerprint = "fingerPrint", 
    SshPrivateKeyPath = "\\PrivateKey\\PrivateKey.ppk ",
};

using (Session session = new Session())
{
    session.Open(sessionOptions);
}
```

But when I run the application and it reaches this like

```
session.Open(sessionOptions);
```

I get this Error:

> Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey,gssapi-with-mic)

Comment: Does your key is password-protected?

Comment: yeah it is. where do i set the password for the ppk file ?

Comment: See http://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_passphrase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use private key without password or pageant, since WinSCP C# classes don't support setting password for private key.

Comment: do you have ny idea what else i can use, that allows me to set the password of a ppk file ?

Comment: There is free/opensource C# BouncyCastle library, they should support SFTP. Also there is commercial SecureBlackbox library, it definitely supports SFTP and private key passwords.

Comment: WinSCP will support providing private key passphrase in .NET assembly since version 5.6: http://winscp.net/tracker/show_bug.cgi?id=816

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of WinSCP .NET assembly does support setting passphrase to an encrypted private key.

Use the [`SessionOptions.PrivateKeyPassphrase`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_sessionoptions#privatekeypassphrase).

```
SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
{
    ...
    SshPrivateKeyPath = "\\PrivateKey\\PrivateKey.ppk",
    SshPrivateKeyPassphrase = "passphrase",
};
```

See also [Automating private key authentication](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_passphrase#automating) in WinSCP FAQ.